# Case insensitive search in Crafer CMS with elasticsearch?

Tags: crafter-cms

I wanted to implement auto-completion with type head, following [this](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/search-elasticsearch.html) documentation, I was able to achieve that. But the search was case sensitive.

Following [this](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/content-modeling.html) documentation, it says, to enable case insensitive search I should select `Tokenize for indexing` option, [this way](https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/_images/tokenize-for-indexing-property.jpg).

I am using crafter CMS 3.1.0 version and I don't use any `Tokenize for indexing` option;
[image]

Note: The version used in documentation is 3.1.9, is this feature not available in 3.1.0?

Answer (score 1):

the feature should work in 3.1.0 too. Keep in mind that after you enable the "Tokenize for indexing" option you will need to reindex all existing content and change your query to use the new field with the `_t` postfix.

Comment: as you can see in the attached image, there is no option for `Tokenize for indexing`. Now in such case, how should I proceed? @Jose Ross

Comment: even if I add new input element, I just see two options `1. Display size 2. Max length` in the properties.